# Cannot Retrieve data from Firebase Database into my Android App

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I have stored data into the Firebase Database, but I am unable to retrieve a set of data.
The `getPname()`, `getDescription()`, `getPrice()` and the image is not showing up.I can only see the button of `Add to cart` and the `ElegantButton` but it shows the text written in `activity_products_category` that is it shows statically product price, product name, product description and does not replace it with the actual in the database.

Below I have attached the Firebase structure. Kindly help.

**ProductsDetailsActivity.java :**

```
 package com.example.giftngame;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton;
import com.example.giftngame.Model.Products;
import com.example.giftngame.Prevalent.Prevalent;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ProductDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Button addToCartButton;
    private ImageView productImage;
    private ElegantNumberButton numberButton;
    private TextView productPrice,productDescription,productName;
    private String productID="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_details);

        productID = getIntent().getStringExtra("pid");

        addToCartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pd_add_to_cart_button);
        numberButton = (ElegantNumberButton) findViewById(R.id.number_btn);
        productImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.product_image_details);
        productPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_price);
        productDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_description_details);
        productName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_name_details);

        getProductDetails(productID);
    }

    private void getProductDetails(String productID)
    {
        final DatabaseReference productsRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");
        productsRef.child("Products").child(productID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    Products products=dataSnapshot.getValue(Products.class);

                    productName.setText(products.getPname());
                    productDescription.setText(products.getDescription());
                    productPrice.setText(products.getPrice());
                    Picasso.get().load(products.getImage()).into(productImage);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

}
```

**Products.java :**

```
package com.example.giftngame.Model;

public class Products
{
    private String pid,pname,price,description,image,category,date,time;


    public Products()
    {

    }

    public Products(String pname, String description, String price, String image, String category, String pid, String date, String time)
    {
        this.pname = pname;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.image = image;
        this.category = category;
        this.pid = pid;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getPname() {
        return pname;
    }

    public void setPname(String pname) {
        this.pname = pname;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String  getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String  image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getPid() {
        return pid;
    }

    public void setPid(String pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

This is the one of the Item's description in detail

[image: This is the one of the Item's description in detail]

Answer (score 0):

According to your firebase structure Products child is an itemtype(Keychain) which has childs like item1, item2. You are not querying firebase database correctly. It should be like

```
 DatabaseReference productsRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");
 productsRef.child(itemType(like Keychain)).child(productID).addValueEventListener
```

**is itemType(Keychain) is fixed or dynamic?** If it is dynamic then code will be different. Let me know.

Comment: Keychain item is one of many items and there are in total 8 items namely(Keychain,Mug,Paperweight,Penholder,Perfume,Photoframe,Teddybear,Windchime) and these are all childs of Products

Comment: The ProductDetailsActivity.java is set to be common for all.So i don't have option to particularly write itemType Keychain

Comment: how you are starting product details activity

Comment: i didn't understand your question

Comment: how you are starting ProductDetailsActivity activity. is this your main activity?

Comment: No this isn't my main activity

Answer (score 0):

You used twice the child `Products` there. It is wrong.

```
final DatabaseReference productsRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");
productsRef.child("Products").child(productID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {...
```

I see you want to display the product's detail. You can use query for your condition. Try this:-

```
private void getProductDetails(final String productID)
{
    final DatabaseReference productsRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");
    final Query queryProductDetail = productRef.orderByChild("pid").equalTo(productID);
    productsRef.child("Products").child(productID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
            {
                Products products = dataSnapshot.getValue(Products.class);
            productName.setText(products.getPname());
            productDescription.setText(products.getDescription());
            productPrice.setText(products.getPrice());
            Picasso.get().load(products.getImage()).into(productImage);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
   });
}
```